# Using string.Join() to avoid a trailing comma

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to put together a list of email addresses into a string, like this:

```
string bcc = string.empty
foreach (contact as Contact in contacts)
{
    bcc = bcc + contact.Email + ","
}
```

The problem with that approach is that the final string has a trailing comma.  Not a huge deal, but I'd like to avoid it, just to be tidy.  So, I tried this:

```
bcc = bcc.Join(",", contact.Email);
```

But that throws an error:

> Member 'string.Join(string, params string[])' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

So, I tried this:

```
bcc = String.Join(",", contact.Email);
```

But that just clears out `bcc` each time and all I end up with is the last email address.  So, I tried this:

```
bcc = bcc + string.Join(",", contact.Email);
```

But that gets me a long string of un-delimited emails with no comma separation.

I'm sure when I see the solution, I'll smack my forehead.  But I'm not grasping it.

Comment: Just to add to Peter B, you use the Join (a static method) on string class not bcc instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what you should use:

```
// using System.Linq;
bcc = string.Join(",", contacts.Select(c => c.Email));
```

And then you don't need the foreach anymore, Linq does it for you.

Answer (score -2):

Adding to @Peter's answer, and from [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5161f838-e722-4481-99a2-cdf33dd18fb9/remove-last-comma-from-a-string-variable?forum=aspcsharp) you can join then trim last comma:

```
bcc = string.Join(",", contacts.Select(c => c.Email)).TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: No need to trim the last comma, Join doesn't add that

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33058367)